# How to print scoreboard for a 3-stage pipeline architecture in python? Getting function not subscriptable error

Tags: python-2.7, cpu-architecture, pipelining

```
def scoreboard(opcode, reg1):
   oc = opcode
   r = reg1
   scoreboard[oc][r]
   return scoreboard




print ('****PIPELINING*****')
while( 1 ):
   stage_count = stage_count+1
   print '\n---PIPE STAGE', stage_count, '---'

if (ic == 0):
  ip, ic, opcode, reg1, reg2, addr = if_id(ip,ic)
  clock = clock + 2;

  opc, reg1 = scoreboard(opcode,reg1)
  print scoreboard
  #print ("----Instruction Fetch & Instruction Decode ----")
  print 'IF&ID: operation:', opcodes[ opcode ] [1]
  if_id_flag = 0
  of_ex_flag = 0
  wb_flag = 0
```

These are two parts of my execute code for assembler.I am getting an error in  scoreboard code: function not subscriptable. Is there any other way of implementing this code? I want to print the scoreboard for a 3 stage pipeline i.e. opcode and register.

Answer (score 0):

`scoreboard` is a function, but the highlighted line is subscripting it like an array.  Fix that.  Do you have a global array with the same name as the function?

```
def scoreboard(opcode, reg1):
   oc = opcode
   r = reg1
   scoreboard[oc][r]  # <<<<<<
   return scoreboard
```